# Create an int var with Ansible's ternary operator

Tags: ansible, casting

I'd like to create a var in my Ansible role that depends on a test and must be an **int**.

```yaml
openldap_ctn_ldap_port: "{{ (openldap_ldap_port >= 1024) | ternary(openldap_ldap_port, openldap_unprivileged_ldap_port) | int }}"
```

Unfortunately, the var is of **str** type instead of **int** as specified by the filter (and expected for a port number).

I know it with this test:

```yaml
- name: Display openldap_ctn_ldap_port created from ternary filter
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: "{{ openldap_ctn_ldap_port }} is of type {{ openldap_ctn_ldap_port | type_debug }}"
```

I get: `"msg": "1389 is of type str"`

How to set that variable as an **int** value ?