# Render numbers inside an Ansible yaml template

Tags: ansible, casting, jinja2, ansible-template

Very close to [Create an int var with Ansible's ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77387515/create-an-int-var-with-ansibles-ternary-operator) and that answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/69109779/446302

In an Ansible project, I'm trying to have a yaml template file with integer content like so:

```yaml
---
my_service:
  enable_ipv6: false
  node_listen:
    - port: '{{ http_port | int }}'
      ip: '{{ srv_ip }}'
```

Unfortunately, it renders to:

```yaml
---
my_service:
  enable_ipv6: false
  node_listen:
    - port: '8080'
      ip: '192.0.0.2'
```

The application I'm using is strict about port type, which means it crashes unless I can give it an int port number.

How can I cast it knowing that I need to keep it inside a template file, due to loops for other sub-settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a [Jinja2 Template](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#expressions) file **`service.yml.j2`** as **input**

```yaml
---
my_service:
  enable_ipv6: false
  node_listen:
    - port: {{ HTTP_PORT }}
      ip: '{{ SRV_IP }}'
```

**processing** via a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) playbook **`main.yml`**

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    HTTP_PORT: 8080
    SRV_IP: 127.0.0.1

  tasks:

  - template:
      src: service.yml.j2  #  input file
      dest: service.yml    # output file
```

will result into an **output** file **`service.yml`** with content of

```yaml
---
my_service:
  enable_ipv6: false
  node_listen:
    - port: 8080
      ip: '127.0.0.1'
```

Comment: Argh ... I was mixing Ansible's yml syntax and yml in a Jinja2 file.
Thnks !

Answer (score 1):

Given the template

```yaml
shell> cat my_service.yml
---
my_service:
  enable_ipv6: false
  node_listen:
    port: {{ http_port }}
    ip: {{ srv_ip }}
```

and the variables

```yaml
  http_port: 8080
  srv_ip: 192.0.0.2
```

Use the *template* lookup plugin to read it

```yaml
  data: "{{ lookup('template', 'my_service.yml')|from_yaml }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  data:
    my_service:
      enable_ipv6: false
      node_listen:
        ip: 192.0.0.2
        port: 8080
```

```yaml
  data.my_service.node_listen.port|type_debug: int
```

See [Return integer value without quote when using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77393300/6482561)

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    http_port: 8080
    srv_ip: 192.0.0.2
    data: "{{ lookup('template', 'my_service.yml')|from_yaml }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: data

    - debug:
        var: data.my_service.node_listen.port

    - debug:
        var: data.my_service.node_listen.port|type_debug
```